# Magento 2 Open All Accordion

Tags: magento-2.0, widgets

I'm trying to make a accordion faq page on mobile but it should be open by default? It's working when i use this line of code `$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "activate" );` is there a counter part for it? I would like to use `data-mage-init` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mention the active tabs by `"active": [0,1,2],`

For example

```
<div id="element" data-mage-init='data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": [0,1,2], "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
```

Comment: I just need to open/active all the accordion by the default when the pages load mate sorry if my question is a bit confusing.

`data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": [0,2], "multipleCollapsible": true}}'` here is my code by the way

Comment: You can use Active element number data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": [0,1,2], "multipleCollapsible": true}}'

Comment: i really want to but i still need to have at least 15 reputation :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers